# WSUS reset questions

Tags: windows-server-2012, wsus, windows-update

I just deployed WSUS on Server 2012 R2 for a 2012 level AD environment. All of the connected machines are Server 2012, 2012 R2 and windows 8.1 (all x64). When I did my first sync WSUS wanted to download ~32,000 updates for every OS Microsoft makes and now wants to download about 81GB of files. I firewalled the server so I can trouble shoot without it blowing my internet connection. Is there anyway to reset things to a fresh state so I can manually select the just the products I need then Let it sync the updates? So basically do a sync like the install is fresh?. I have a GPO set up to register the machines with the server so that is not a worry. All the machines were up to date individually when I registered them in the first place, so when the WSUS server is cleaned is it safe to decline everything and then manage only the new updates?

Thanks,
Nat

Comment: Why don't you just uninstall and re-install WSUS? It's a 15 minute install.

Comment: I tried removing the role and re adding it but that did not reset the approvals for definitions in the database.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the database as well? (Uninstalling WID, deleting DB files)

Comment: @Nat45928 right. That data is stored in the database. You must also remove the database and use a new one with the reinstall.

Comment: I just saw that those are separate roles, I am trying again now. Thanks for the advice.